# Installing Dropbox on Ubuntu 18 Server Failing

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, dropbox

I am following [this](https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux) article to install and tried both methods.
Downloading the headless and the .deb methods I run the following commands:

```
$ ./dropboxd
```

And the DEB:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i dropbox_2020.03.04.deb
$ sudo apt -f install
$ dropbox start
```

For both I'm getting the error:

```
ImportError: libglapi.so.0:
```

I'm new to Linux server and I'm a little bit lost. Should I upgrade my server to Ubuntu 20?

Comment: [Check this post from Dropbox community](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-installs-integrations/Headless-install-on-Debian-libglapi-so-0-cannot-open-shared/td-p/396457)